Bound for Sup norm of piecewise continuous function
I’m working for this paper, but I encountered some problem for proving Lemma 2. It stated that if $\psi \in C([a,b])\cap_{i=1}^n C^2([x_{i-1}, x_i])$, where $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=b$, one has that
$$
||\psi||_\infty \le ||\hat{\psi}||_\infty + \dfrac{h^2}{8}||\psi^{\prime\prime}||_\infty
$$
and
$$
||\psi^\prime||_\infty \le \max_i \left(\dfrac{2}{x_i-x_{i-1}}||\hat{\psi}||_\infty+\dfrac{x_i-x_{i-1}}{2}||\psi^{\prime\prime}||_\infty\right)
$$
Here, $\hat\psi := (\psi(x_0), \ldots, \psi(x_n))^T, h=\max_i(x_i-x_{i-1})$
For the first inequality, I have tried Taylor expansion but I am still confused about the denominator 8. I’m wondering that if I miss some conditions or something else.

Given link is not working

@Guruprasad now the link is working.

@Thomas oky I will see it

I just found this question: this link which is similar to my question but I don’t know how to do without boundary conditions.
